# Find $ \int \frac {\mathrm{d}x}{(4x^2-1)^{3/2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I have trouble using trig sub. After I get that x = 2x+1, should I substitute back into the original problem's $4x^2$ with $(4(2x+1)^2)$?

Comment: I can't find it, can you help me?

Comment: I find it helpful to rewrite $1/(4x^2-1)^{3/2}$ as
$$\frac{1}{(4x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{1}{((2x)^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}}= \frac{1}{(\sec^2(\sec^{-1}(2x))-1)^\frac{3}{2}}=\dots$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Using [Trigonometric substitutions](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/trigsub/trigsub.html),  set $2x=\sec\theta$

$$\implies4x^2-1=\tan^2\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{}$
\begin{align}&\overbrace{\color{#66f}{\large\int{\dd x \over \pars{4x^{2} - 1}^{3/2}}}}
^{\ds{\dsc{x} \equiv \dsc{1 \over t}\ \imp\ \dsc{t} \equiv \dsc{1 \over x}}}\ =\
\int{-\,\dd t/t^{2} \over \pars{4/t^{2} - 1}^{3/2}}
=-\int{t\,\dd t \over \pars{4 - t^{2}}^{3/2}}
=-\pars{4 - t^{2}}^{-1/2}
\\[5mm]&=-\pars{4 - {1 \over x^{2}}}^{-1/2}
=\color{#66f}{\large -\,{x \over \root{4x^{2} - 1}}} + \mbox{a constant}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$y=2x-1 \implies \dfrac{1}{2}dy=dx$

$\therefore\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dx}{\left(4x^2-1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dy}{y^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(y+2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

$y=2\tan^2\theta \implies dy=4\sec^2\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta$

$\therefore\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dy}{y^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(y+2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\displaystyle\int\dfrac{2\sec^2\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta}{2^3\tan^3\theta\sec^3\theta}=\dfrac{1}{4}\displaystyle\int\csc \theta \cot \theta \ d\theta$